# PHP codeigniter Email issue with office365

Tags: php, codeigniter, office365

I have a challenge with send mail using a microsoft office365 email account this is my mail config

```
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.office365.com'; //change this with your smtp host
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'xxxxx'; //your smtp user email
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxx'; //your smtp password
        $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
        $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
```

But the mail keeps bouncing back with the foolowing error log

> Failed to authenticate password. Error:  Unable to send email using
>   PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this
>   method. User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Thu, 23 Mar 2017 06:00:00 -0700
>   From: "Chores.ng"  Return-Path:  To:
>   dflobt@gmail.com Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?TEST?= Reply-To: 
>   X-Sender: info@chores.ng X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
>   Message-ID: <58d3c6d090a7f@chores.ng> Mime-Version: 1.0

But when i log in to the portal.office.com with the credentials used i can access the account but from my code the authentication error keeps showing.
Thanks in anticipation of your response

Comment: Ever find a resolution to this? Having the same problem myself :/

Comment: Yeah ...what i did was going into the codeigniter core Email library class and editing the configuration with all parameters value set with single quote except the newline and the crlf.....But currently i use phpmailer have dropped the codeigniter email library long ago